# Getting an "uninitialized constant Chef::Provider::AwsS3File::RightAws" error when using aws cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use [aws](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/aws) cookbook to download files from S3,

I get this following error :

```
ERROR: aws_s3_file[demo.py] (demo_s3_file::default line 163) had an error: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Provider::AwsS3File::RightAws
```

Can't find anything on this error on Google,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can use any of the LWRP resources provided by the cookbook, you must include the default recipe into your runlist.

This is required because you need to install some additional libraries in order to communicate with S3 (which is exactly what the default recipe does). To quote the README file of the cookbook:

> The default recipe installs the `right_aws` RubyGem, which this cookbook requires in order to work with the EC2 API. Make sure that the aws recipe is in the node or role `run_list` before any resources from this cookbook are used.

Thus, before including your own recipes into the runlist, add this

```
recipe[aws]
```

Comment: This was a very nice way of saying RTFM :). +1